# Find all CTE runtimes in an SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-api

I'm in the process of cleaning up some of our SQL queries in Tableau Online/Snowflake and I have been running each CTE in a query individually to find the run time. Does anybody know of a process to find the runtime of individual CTEs automatically? Running CTEs by themselves is a tedious and (sometimes) slow task, but it has helped us find ways to optimize our costs. It is also complicated when one CTE references other CTEs. I'm also open to python solutions/guidance - I'm a little new to python but have been looking for a project!

This would help us a lot in determining what size warehouse to use for daily caches and target inefficient queries much faster. Since this is business data, I can't share specific queries. Thanks in advance!

Comment: CTE's are just syntactic sugar for a subquery and as subqueries are just SQL code that leads to an execution path, and the steps the RDBMS takes to determine that execution path may split the logic of the subquery to be executed at different times in the process (optimizer decisions like predicate pushdown/pullup, as an example), it may not make sense to do this analysis. Nor would it make sense to do your current analysis where you run them separately. This is one of those cases where the sum of the parts may not equal the whole.

Comment: Not that it's a lost cause, just that thinking of a CTE as a distinct set of execution steps separate from the query that utilizes those CTE's is a misunderstanding of what is happening under the hood.

Comment: It might be a good idea to take a look at [Query Profiler](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile.html) to gain a better understanding of the execution steps being performed for the entire query and where you are spending the most CPU. Perhaps some of those steps could be traced back to particular logic that resides in the CTE's to gain insight into which of the SQL logic is costing the most.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill ! That makes sense re: sum of parts not being the best analysis. Even if runtimes by CTE aren't exact, would it still be useful in finding a section of the code that takes 45 minutes to run when all others take a few minutes? ie. if I was looking for major differences/opportunities for improvement rather than trying to fully automate finding possible optimizations.

Edit: Just saw your comment about Query Profiler - I'll give that a look!

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah that makes sense. I would suggest digging through query profiler to help with the forensics. You may find that helpful when trying to diagnose which part of a big ugly query is causing the most pain. And it could very well be that a particular CTE contains a piece of logic that is acting as the long pole in the tent.

Comment: Christian Scutaru has an excellent Snowflake Query Profiler Python script at https://github.com/cristiscu/query-profiler that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of CTEs you want to manage individually, and especially if some queries re-use CTEs from other queries: Consider using views instead.

When you create a view, you are basically defining a CTE with a name, that can be referenced by multiple queries - and that you can individually benchmark and test.

As you grow your views dependency trees, dbt turns out to be a great toolbox to manage them, their tests, and their dependencies.

Comment: I have been thinking about creating some more views. We have quite a few of them already and my idea was to find the CTE's that have the highest runtime and create a view that is cached daily. If that CTE is used across multiple dashboard, even better. The end goal is faster tableau dashboards that are also easier to edit. I'll check out dbt - thanks for the rec!